# Avoid recursive replacement on a string

Tags: java, string, replace

Assume there is a string:

```
"I'm a boy."
```

and some synonyms words (in key-value format):

```
boy -> "male yong"
yong -> "age under 18"
```

If I replace the string by synonyms words **one by one**, it will be:

Step 1, find word "boy" and replace it: `"I'm a male young."`
Step 2, find word "young" and replace it: `"I'm a male age under 18."`
Actually I need not recursive replacement, I need only replace the orginal string, in other words the step 2 should find "young" in orginal string:"I'm a boy." not the "I'm a male young." There is a simple solution:

Firstly replace key to %s and add synonyms word to a list:

```
string: "I'm a %s"
list: "male yong"
```

Then format string with list:

```
String.format(string, list)
```

It works fine but stupid and slow, anyone have more clear solution?

Comment: I'm not sure what your actual task is, but if you need to exclude the result of previous translations from any further changes, then control the **starting point** of your search/replace.

Comment: If you can clearly identify which synonym values contain other synonyms, then you can imagine a 'graph' structure where all the synonyms that will not evaluate to other synonyms are replaced first, followed by their 'parents' and so on until you have safely evaluated all synonyms. If there are cycles is this graph, though, you are out of luck.

Comment: Can synonyms be arbitrary strings, or only single words (e.g. with no whitespace in their keys)? If the latter, then you can `split` the string on whitespace, and for each string in the split attempt synonyms on it and move on if you find none or if you applied one. That way no word will be synonymized recursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pseudo code (not Tested and function names might be wrong):

```
String[] arr = sentence.Split(" ");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); //can specify size for better results possibly

for (String s :arr ){
   if ( dic.contains(s) ){
       sb.append(dic.get(s));
   }else{
       sb.append(s);
   }
}

sb.toString();//your replaced string
```

I am not sure what string.format  does internally but it might be doing something similar so I doubt you will get a performance boost.

Comment: Surely you mean to split on white space, not on the empty string? Otherwise, assuming synonym keys never have whitespace in them, something like this is the right answer.

Comment: Hmm - and if the sentence has punctuation in it, for example the fragment "boy." would not be in the dictionary as "boy". So I think you need to split on... hmm... `\b`? (`\b` matches the boundary between a word character (`[0-9a-zA-Z_]`) and a non word character (anything else), so it will fracture hyphenated words but be fine on all others.)

Comment: @Patashu that depends on the the domain of the problem. The above code should not be hard to modify to meet any specific requirements. Its pseudo code anyways. (In worst case regexps)

Answer (score 0):

This solution is similar to yours but it does not use String.format

```
    String s = "I'm a yong boy.";
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("boy", "male yong");
    map.put("yong", "age under 18");
    // replace all keys with 1 char placeholders 
    int i = 0;
    for (String key : map.keySet()) {
        s = s.replace(key, "" + (char) i++);
    }
    // replace placeholders with values
    int j = 0;
    for (String v : map.values()) {
        s = s.replace("" + (char) j++, v);
    }
    System.out.println(s);
```

output

```
I'm a age under 18 male yong.
```

Speed can be improved if we used StringBuilder for replacement but it would be much longer code. It's safe if replacement number is less than 31, after that it will start replacing spaces